# The correct way of creating a Factory for creating domain objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

The following is the code from my service layer

```
@Override
    public Boolean saveTransportation(SaveTransportationCommand addServiceCommand)  {
        return getServiceAgreementDao().saveTransportation((List<Transportation>)ServiceAgreementFactory.get(addServiceCommand));
}
```

I am trying to create domain objects from `Command object`, can I do validations and set values from command in Factory, is my approach correct, Or should I user Factory for only creating objects.

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Comment: done formatting the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory is used for creating objects. In my opinion, it is not a crime to do validations and setting values inside factory methods before creating objects. If you are too concerned about the Factory doing such things (If you want your factory loosely coupled), you can have a `Validator` interface and pass it as an argument to Factory. Inside get method, you first validate. If the validate returns true, instantiate the object or else throw Exception.

```
public interface Validator {
   boolean validate(SaveTransportationCommand command);
}
```

Modify the `ServiceAgreementFactory.get()` to take in `Validator` also.

```
public class ServiceAgreementFactory {

  List<Transportation> get(SaveTransportationCommand command, Validator validator) {
      if(!validator.validate(command)) {
        // throw Exception
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Consider upvoting  the questions/answers in stack overflow so that the other users will know it is helpful :)

Comment: My initial thoughts were, the factory will do the creation of object, I thought of building the domain object concern to be separated, building in the Factory will do not harm.

Comment: Sometimes there is nothing wrong in doing certain stuff since there is not always one right way to do things :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm assuming that you are creating a list of `Transportation` from the `ServiceAgreementFactory`? If so, it is not important where the `get()` method is called. Usually, a factory has a method for instantiating one instance and the method for instantiating a list is simply a loop of that method.

There is nothing wrong with using a static method for a factory. Personally, I prefer declaring an interface for the factory and providing a default implementation. This way, code that uses the factory is only coupled to the interface and not the implementation.

An example would be as follows.

```
public interface ServiceAgreementFactory {
    Transportation get(SaveTransportationCommand command);
    default List<Transportation> getList(SaveTransportationCommand command) {
        // loop to call get(SaveTransportationCommand)
    }
}

public class DefaultServiceAgreementFactory implements ServiceAgreementFactory {
    Transportation get(SaveTransportationCommand command) {
        // instantiating code
    }
}
```

As for validation, you can do it in the factory. Example as follows.

```
public class DefaultServiceAgreementFactory implements ServiceAgreementFactory {
    Transportation get(SaveTransportationCommand command) {
        // validation code
        if (validation fails) {
            // throw exception
        }
        // instantiating code
    }
}
```

As the prior post suggests, it would be cleaner to abstract away the validation code.